# Java program for getting and setting inputs total run, total match played about cricket players and finding the average run scored using the input

Tags: java, object, methods, getter, setter

I created this code involving two classes one class `player` class has all the variables and getter and setter method  and the `solution` class finds the average run using the input of total runs and total match played.

The players will be classified into 3 categories according to their average run. My code is working fine without any error but the average score always shows 0.

### Player class

```
public class Player {
    private int id;
    private int iccRank;
    private int matchPlayed;
    private double averageRun;
    private int totalRun;
    private String name;
}
```

### Solution class

```
class Solution{
    float a,b,c;

    public static void findAvgOfRun(Player my) {
        float a=my.gettotalRun();
        float b=my.getmatchPlayed();
        float c= a/b;
        my.setaverageRun(c);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player my = new Player();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Player name: ");
        my.setname(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Player ID: ");
        my.setid(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Enter Player ICC Rank: ");
        my.seticcRank(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Enter number of match played: ");
        my.setmatchPlayed(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Enter Player total run: ");
        my.settotalRun(sc.nextInt());
        sc.close();
        if(my.getaverageRun()<=100 && my.getaverageRun()>=80) {
            System.out.println("He is a grade A player");
        }
        else if(my.getaverageRun()<80 && my.getaverageRun()>=50) {
            System.out.println("He is a grade B player");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("He is a grade C player");
        }
        
        my.display();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `findAvgOfRun`?

Comment: ohhh yeah sorry I forgot that!! Now its working thank you so much!! I am new to programming I learning java for a week now. Thank you for spending your time for answering

Answer (score 0):

Please see line where I added comment:

```
public static void findAvgOfRun(Player my) {
    float a=my.gettotalRun();
    float b=my.getmatchPlayed();
    float c= a/b;
    my.setaverageRun(c);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player my = new Player();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Player name: ");
    my.setname(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Enter Player ID: ");
    my.setid(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.print("Enter Player ICC Rank: ");
    my.seticcRank(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.print("Enter number of match played: ");
    my.setmatchPlayed(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.print("Enter Player total run: ");
    my.settotalRun(sc.nextInt());
    sc.close();
    Solution.findAvgOfRun(my); //In place of solution use your class name in which main method is there.
    if(my.getaverageRun()<=100 && my.getaverageRun()>=80) {
        System.out.println("He is a grade A player");
    }
    else if(my.getaverageRun()<80 && my.getaverageRun()>=50) {
        System.out.println("He is a grade B player");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("He is a grade C player");
    }
    
    my.display();
}
```